# Wordpress - Some search results not showing up

Tags: wordpress, search, relevanssi

We have a [website](http://dev.hayball.net.au) that we've taken over. There is a custom post type called "projects".

If we do a search using the term "learning" on the `frontend`, the results do not show a project with the title "Caulfield Grammar School, Masterplan & Learning Project" even though the term "learning" is in the title. Yet if we search using the term "Caulfield" it appears in the search results.

The site is running the [Relevanssi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/) and even with it disabled that search result does not appear. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'mjt_project_search' );
function mjt_project_search( $query ) {

    if ( $query->is_search ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'projects') );
    $query->set( 'post_status', array( 'publish') );
    }

    return $query;

}

/*custom texonomy */
function mjt_search_where($where){
  global $wpdb;
  if (is_search())
    $where .= "OR (t.name LIKE '%".get_search_query()."%' AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish')";
  return $where;
}

function mjt_search_join($join){
  global $wpdb;
  if (is_search())
    $join .= "LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = tr.object_id INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id=tr.term_taxonomy_id INNER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id";
  return $join;
}

function mjt_search_groupby($groupby){
  global $wpdb;

  // we need to group on post ID
  $groupby_id = "{$wpdb->posts}.ID";
  if(!is_search() || strpos($groupby, $groupby_id) !== false) return $groupby;

  // groupby was empty, use ours
  if(!strlen(trim($groupby))) return $groupby_id;

  // wasn't empty, append ours
  return $groupby.", ".$groupby_id;
}

add_filter('posts_where','mjt_search_where');
add_filter('posts_join', 'mjt_search_join');
add_filter('posts_groupby', 'mjt_search_groupby');
```

Comment: Hi,

Did you see my response? Things aren't working as before. Thanks

Comment: any response on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Caulfield Grammar School, Masterplan & Learning Project"
is this are custom taxonomy?

If yes, we need to update query for Taxonomy too.

Answer (score 0):

That has kind of worked but there are other post types which it will need to show the results of so I changed the code to this:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'mjt_project_search' );
function mjt_project_search( $query ) {

    if ( $query->is_search ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'projects', 'news', 'award', 'person', 'location', 'page') );
    $query->set( 'post_status', array( 'publish') );
    }

    return $query;

}
```

That has worked but it isn't showing the 'Caulfield Grammar School, Masterplan & Learning Project' now.