# Relevanssi Wordpress Search Results

Tags: wordpress, search, relevanssi

We have a clients website (http://hayball.com.au) running the Relevanssi Wordpress Plugin (https://www.relevanssi.com).

Client has noticed that certain results do not appear when searched for. For example, searching for the term 'learning' should show all results that contain 'learning' as the search term. It does not show the project named "Caulfield Grammar School, Masterplan & Learning Project" even though the search term is in the title.

If you then use "caulfield" as the search term it shows that project. This is the code that displays the search results in the theme.

```
<?php if (have_posts()): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php
            $posttype = get_post_type();
            $link = '';
            $readmore = '';
            $excerpt = '';

            if( $posttype == 'projects' ) {
                $category = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'sector');
                $primaryCat = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_yoast_wpseo_primary_sector',true);
                if($primaryCat){
                    $category = null;
                    $primary = get_term($primaryCat, 'sector');
                    $category[] = $primary;
                }
                $link = '<a href="/projects/">' . $project . '</a>';

                if($category) {
                    $link = $link . ' / <a href="/projects/#' . $category[0]->slug . '">' . $category[0]->name . '</a>';
                }
                $link = $link . ' / <a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
                $readmore = get_the_permalink();
                $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();

            }

            if( $posttype == 'news' ) {
                $category = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'category');
                $link = '<a href="/news/">' . $exchange . '</a>';
                if($category) {
                    $link = $link . ' / <a href="/news/#' . $category[0]->slug . '">' . $category[0]->name . '</a>';
                }
                $link = $link . ' / <a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
                $readmore = get_the_permalink();
                $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
            }

            if( $posttype == 'award' ) {
                $link = ''; //'<a href="/practice/awards/">Awards</a>';
                $readmore = '/practice/awards/';
                $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
            }

            if( $posttype == 'person' ) {
                $link = ''; //'<a href="/practice/people/">People</a>';
                $readmore = '/practice/people/';
                $excerpt = get_the_title();
            }

            if( $posttype == 'location' ) {
                $link = ''; //'<a href="/contact/">Contact</a>';
                $readmore = '/contact/';
                $excerpt = get_field('address');
            }

            if( $posttype == 'page' ) {
                $link = ''; //'<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
                $readmore = get_the_permalink();
            }
        ?>
        <li id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
            <div class="content">
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                <p class="link">
                    <?php echo $link; ?>
                </p>
                <p><?php echo $excerpt; ?></p>

                <a href="<?php echo $readmore; ?>"><?php echo translation('read_more'); ?></a>
            </div>

            <?php if(wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()), 'thumbnail'  )) : ?>

            <div class="image" style="background-image: url('<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()), 'thumbnail'  ); echo $image[0]; ?>')"></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php else: ?>
    <p>
        0 <?php echo translation('results'); ?>
    </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I was also told to try adding this to the functions.php It seems to not have done anything.

```
function mjt_project_search( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_search ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'projects', 'news', 'award', 'person', 'location', 'page') );
    $query->set( 'post_status', array( 'publish') );
}
return $query;}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'mjt_project_search' );`
```

When the plugin is disabled it displays the results properly yet the client requires high relevance on all search results, hence the use of the Relevanssi plugin.

Any help or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Dayne

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress - Some search results not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534638/wordpress-some-search-results-not-showing-up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the previous developer of the website before our agency took it over neglected to build pagination into the search results. So it did appear but on page 3. Haha.

Thanks for everyones help.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Relevanssi for a couple years but am not an expert.  I have not had a situation where it failed to find a search term if it existed in any of our posts. Since the post is found when searching for caulfield, that implies the post has been indexed.  I added a post to my site with the title you provided above.  Relevansii returned the post when searching for "learning or learn". The only way I could reproduce the post not being found was to add "learning" to the Relevanssi stop word list.  Make sure it is not in your list of stop words.  There is a Relevanssi option under Settings/indexing/Show Advanced Settings to replace ampersands with spaces.  I tested your post title replacing the ampersands with spaces and again keeping the ampersands.  It was found both times.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.